# Internationalization of Dynamic content using spring or angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I need a help on doing a internationalization of dynamic content. Let's suppose I have a application which is working in different region like jersey, Philippines, Argentina etc. I need to show content based on the country user's login. **I already know how to show it for labels**. But for dynamic content, I unable to think how to proceed. For eg. if a user login in a particular region, I need to show his name in that particular region language or If he changes his language preference then need to show based on the selected preference.

I am using spring and angularjs in my application.

How to proceed for this?

Comment: Generally names doesn't need to be translated, but for other data values you just need to return json objects of keys to angular app and in angular they should be translated based on active language using directives like angular-translate.

Answer (score 1):

I made one  `angular` application with just the requirement you said. i18n and l10n.

- `angular-translate` for dynamic label translations
- `angular-i18n` for localization.
- `angular-dynamic-locale` for dynamic localization.

**EDIT EXAMPLE**

Simple page http://the-unsoul.github.io/angular-requireJS/#/home (only couple fields got its label tranlating)

Source code https://github.com/the-unsoul/angular-requireJS

Comment: Thanks Linh, can you provide any example for dynamic translation. it will be a great help.

Comment: Back there I have settup a simple seed example (for learning purpose). ----
This is the page http://the-unsoul.github.io/angular-requireJS/#/home (I only settup some labels and 1 singe datetime field with localization. ---- This is the source code https://github.com/the-unsoul/angular-requireJS . ---- Even it is simple but if you are new to angular, take your time to read through because it may be overwhelming for new user.

Comment: @user1111880 please upvote if you found the answer useful. Cheers! :)